# Should I use itertuples or iterrows for iteration of Dataframes

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, parsing

This is a pet project wherein I parse the CSV into a human-readable format as a *.txt, CSV (CSV may contain 100k+ rows)

like this,

```
name,type,start_time,duration,ack,address,read,data
I2C,start,23.6799126,8.00E-09,,,,
I2C,address,23.6799138,8.40E-06,TRUE,0x74,FALSE,
I2C,data,23.6799239,8.40E-06,TRUE,,,0x02
I2C,start,23.6799367,8.00E-09,,,,
I2C,address,23.6799409,8.40E-06,TRUE,0x74,TRUE,
I2C,data,23.6799509,8.40E-06,FALSE,,,0xB2
I2C,stop,23.6799619,8.00E-09,,,,
```

For every row item, I will decode whether it's a type==Start or address or data or stop and then parse the other values appropriately, for I am using itertuples for the entire data frame. I also get input from a JSON file example correlates it with the CSV.

```
 {
     "name":"IOUT_LIMIT",
     "address":"0x02",
     "Formulate":"1",
     "Data_Width":"1",
     "Mask":"0x7F",
     "Weightage":"50",
     "Offset":"0",
     "Units":"mA",
     "BitFields":[
        {
           "name":"",
           "start":0,
           "end":7
        }
     ]
  },
```

**And output as**

```
Transaction started for:  Read Data From  IOUT_LIMIT 3100mA
Transaction started for:  Write Data To  IOUT_LIMIT 3250mA
```

**Example code**

```
for row in df.itertuples():
        
        #Check for Start or Stop; I2C Start is used to start a transaction, If we encounter Repeated start it's a read.

        if(row.type == 'start'):
            
            #Fresh Start Encountered
            if(Transaction_Started == 0):
                String = "Transaction started for : "
                Transaction_Started = 1
            else:
                #Repeated start encountered
                Repeated_Start = 1
                
        elif (row.type == 'address'):
            
            if(Repeated_Start == 0):
                Slave_address = row.address
            
        elif(row.type == 'data'):
            
            #Append read data to a list "Data"
            Data.append(row.data)
            
            if(Repeated_Start):
                String+=" Read Data From"
            else:
                if(DataWrite == 1):
                    String+=" Write Data To"
                    
            DataWrite+=1
        
        elif(row.type == 'stop'):
            #Iterate over Regcmd_List in the JSON
            for i in DataSheet_Data['Regcmd_List']:
                
                #If Address is Hit Get the Register name and Store in Output 
                Data and move along
                #Data[0] will have address byte
                if(i['address'] == Data[0]):
                    Output_Data = i['name']
                    
                    #Get the Datawidth
                    Datawidth = int(i['Data_Width'],0)
                    Temp_Data = ""
                    
                    #Iterate the Stored Data from Data[1] and Store them as 
                     a single value in Temp_Data
                    #Temp_data will have only Data, Address byte will be 
                    excluded since we are iterating from Index[Datawidth]
                    #to Index[1]
                    for j in range(Datawidth,0,-1):
                        Data[j] = Data[j].replace("0x","")
                        Temp_Data+=Data[j]
                    
                    #Check for Formula and apply over the Temp_Data
                    if(i['Formulate'] == '1'):
                    
                        #Multiply the value with Weightage and add offset if 
                        mentoined in Json
                        Temp_Data = int(Temp_Data,16)
                        Temp_Data &= int(i['Mask'],0)
                        Temp_Data *= int(i['Weightage'])
                        if((i['Offset'] != "0") & (Temp_Data!=0)):
                            Temp_Data += int(i['Offset'])
                            
                        Temp_Data = str(Temp_Data)
                        
                        #Append this to Output_Data which will  have the  
                        Register Name + Value after Formula calculation
                        Output_Data += " " + Temp_Data
                        String_Units = i['Units']
                        
                    else:
                        #Append this to Output_Data which will  have the 
                        Register Name + Raw Bytes 
                        Output_Data += " " + "0x" +Temp_Data
                        
            print(String + " " + " " + Output_Data + String_Units,file=output_file)
            
            #Clear all the context when an I2C Stop is Encountered
            Transaction_Started = 0
            Slave_address = 0
            Repeated_Start = 0
            DataWrite = 0
            String_Units = ""
            Output_Data = ""
            Temp_Data = ""
            Datawidth = 0
            Data.clear()
```

**For this application should I use `iterrows` or `itertuples` which is efficient?**

One efficient way can be to read the N rows from when I encounter `row.type == 'start'` to `row.type == 'stop'` and process the frames. But can even for that I may need to iterate till I hit stop and do the bulk of my processing when I encounter a Stop. If there are more performance benefit designs kindly let me know.

Comment: Please provide your data as text rather than image.

Comment: Guessing the "L" is an abbreviation for an Indian word. Please don't use them here, we're not all from India.

Comment: `itertuples` is always faster than `iterrow`. Both are relatively inefficient. You should probably just use the `csv` module for this

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, `String += "some other string"` is inefficient

Comment: Btw can you post your expected output from the given dataframe?

Comment: you can convert the dataframe to dict - `df.to_dict('records')` and then iterate over it. I guess it'll be the faster option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate over the CSV file one line at a time, it will avoid loading the entire 100k row file into memory.

My answer below treats each row as an event that is printed to standard output. However, in your original post, your data has multiple 'start' events before a 'stop' event. Does the 'stop' event stop all currently open transactions?

```py
def csv_to_message(filename) -> None:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        first_line = next(f)
        headers = first_line.split(',')
        transaction = {}
        for row_str in f:
            row_array = row_str.strip().split(',')
            row_dict = {k: (v if v else None) for k,v in zip(headers, row_array)}

            if row_dict['type']=='start':
                # update data in transaction
                # Augment transaction with data from JSON...
                # optionally choose to print message
            elif row_dict['type']=='address':
                # update data in transaction
                # Augment transaction with data from JSON...
                # optionally choose to print message
            elif row_dict['type']=='data':
                # update data in transaction
                # Augment transaction with data from JSON...
                # optionally choose to print message
            elif row_dict['type']=='stop':
                # update data in transaction
                # Augment transaction with data from JSON...
                # optionally choose to print message
                # Clear the transaction dictionary
                transaction = {}

            # print(f'Transaction {"started" if row_dict["type"]=="start" else "stopped"} for {"READ" if row_dict["read"] is True else "WRITE"} {("data: " + transaction["data"]) if transaction["data"] else ""} at ...etc...')
```

The print() function at the end would print once per event, and if you use the f-string expressions like in my example it can summarize the information currently in row_dict (for the individual event info), or in transaction (for summary info). You also form the conditional components of the string as you go and print out once at the end.

I realize this does not use pandas, but nothing about the scenerio you described seems to require loading the entire pandas module into memory either. Always nice to avoid external modules when possible.

Also, since this python's open() function can accept a path-like object as input, you can stream from stdin or some other source. At the end of the day, you are streaming data and should use a streaming pattern with the 'transaction' variable as a sort of buffer rather than load everything into memory before operating on it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your further calculations are, but one approach could be associating the rows between first start and stop, and then processing them via grouping, to get total duration, count of starts, etc.

suppose this is the csv called IC2.csv:

```
name,type,start_time,duration,ack,address,read,data
I2C,start,23.6799126,8.00E-09,,,,
I2C,address,23.6799138,8.40E-06,TRUE,0x74,FALSE,
I2C,data,23.6799239,8.40E-06,TRUE,,,0x02
I2C,start,23.6799367,8.00E-09,,,,
I2C,address,23.6799409,8.40E-06,TRUE,0x74,TRUE,
I2C,data,23.6799509,8.40E-06,FALSE,,,0xB2
I2C,stop,23.6799619,8.00E-09,,,,
I2C,start,23.6799126,8.00E-09,,,,
I2C,address,23.6799138,8.40E-06,TRUE,0x74,FALSE,
I2C,data,23.6799239,8.40E-06,TRUE,,,0x02
I2C,start,23.6799367,8.00E-09,,,,
I2C,address,23.6799409,8.40E-06,TRUE,0x74,TRUE,
I2C,data,23.6799509,8.40E-06,FALSE,,,0xB2
I2C,stop,23.6799619,8.00E-09,,,,
```

Then you can read it :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('ic2.csv')
```

to obtain an indexed dataframe like this:

```
name    type    start_time  duration    ack     address     read    data
0   I2C     start   23.679913   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   I2C     address     23.679914   8.400000e-06    True    0x74    False   NaN
2   I2C     data    23.679924   8.400000e-06    True    NaN     NaN     0x02
3   I2C     start   23.679937   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   I2C     address     23.679941   8.400000e-06    True    0x74    True    NaN
5   I2C     data    23.679951   8.400000e-06    False   NaN     NaN     0xB2
6   I2C     stop    23.679962   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
7   I2C     start   23.679913   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
8   I2C     address     23.679914   8.400000e-06    True    0x74    False   NaN
9   I2C     data    23.679924   8.400000e-06    True    NaN     NaN     0x02
10  I2C     start   23.679937   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
11  I2C     address     23.679941   8.400000e-06    True    0x74    True    NaN
12  I2C     data    23.679951   8.400000e-06    False   NaN     NaN     0xB2
13  I2C     stop    23.679962   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

then you can generate the groups, for example:

```
# find indices of type stop
indstop=df.index[df['type']=='stop'].to_list()

# set new column group flagging the stops
df.loc[df['type']=='stop', 'group'] = indstop

# assign group to the remaining rows
df['group'].fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
```

now your df looks like this:

```
name    type    start_time  duration    ack     address     read    data    group
0   I2C     start   23.679913   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     6.0
1   I2C     address     23.679914   8.400000e-06    True    0x74    False   NaN     6.0
2   I2C     data    23.679924   8.400000e-06    True    NaN     NaN     0x02    6.0
3   I2C     start   23.679937   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     6.0
4   I2C     address     23.679941   8.400000e-06    True    0x74    True    NaN     6.0
5   I2C     data    23.679951   8.400000e-06    False   NaN     NaN     0xB2    6.0
6   I2C     stop    23.679962   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     6.0
7   I2C     start   23.679913   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     13.0
8   I2C     address     23.679914   8.400000e-06    True    0x74    False   NaN     13.0
9   I2C     data    23.679924   8.400000e-06    True    NaN     NaN     0x02    13.0
10  I2C     start   23.679937   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     13.0
11  I2C     address     23.679941   8.400000e-06    True    0x74    True    NaN     13.0
12  I2C     data    23.679951   8.400000e-06    False   NaN     NaN     0xB2    13.0
13  I2C     stop    23.679962   8.000000e-09    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     13.0
```

and you can now do aggregation by groups, for instance:

```
df.groupby('group').agg({'duration':'sum'})


    duration
group   
6.0     0.000034
13.0    0.000034
```

Comment: But after grouping I want to parse each line comparing the data to json and get a readable output

Comment: I see, it's quite a complex piece of work. Once thing you could do is bring the json file to a data frame, compare and then convert the results to json, and as mentioned by Nk03 in comments, df.to_dict() will also help. But If it comes to row by row as per your original question, then itertuples will be faster than iterrows; there is a good article about it here: https://medium.com/swlh/why-pandas-itertuples-is-faster-than-iterrows-and-how-to-make-it-even-faster-bc50c0edd30d